# How do I convert a second value ("120") into time format ("2:00") in EXCEL?

Tags: excel

I have many data like 250, 121, 56 which means seconds.

I want to convert them in EXCEL into a more understandable format, which should look like a time format, for example:

250 -> 4:10
121 -> 2:01
56 -> 0:56

Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to divide your integer by 1440 and divide it by 60, if you're using seconds as your starting data.  Then format the resulting cell as `Time` format.  See this [Mr. Excel question.](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/2641-convert-seconds-time-display-hh-mm-ss.html)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any easier way?

Comment: OK. Thanks! But this needs an extra placeholder, right? I need to put this in a new cell. I can't do it just by typing this formula in the original cell itself. Just want to confirm whether I have to do this.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to run this in a new column.  You can then `Paste Special` just the values back when you're done.

Comment: Dividing by 1440 and then multiplying by 60 gives the wrong answer. In the link the formula is `=A1/(1440*60) - parentheses are crucial because 1440*60 is performed first to give 86400 and then A1 is divided by that so it's the equivalent of diving by 86400 or actually dividing by 1440 and then dividing by 60, i.e.